# highlight "" in strings for emacs

Tags: emacs, font-lock

I am a bit of an emacs noob, but not quite sure how to even find this. I use [solarized light](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color theme, which is a low contrast theme with intelligent accents to keep things readable. One thing they do in the vim version is highlight the string delimiters (meaning double quote and single quote in some languages) differently then the rest of the string to make them stand out more.

The emacs port of the theme does not have this, however I have seen some pretty crazy stuff happen with the font locking mechanism (like this http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HexColour), so I figured it was possible.

So is it possible to highlight string delimeters? if so, where should I look for more info on how to do it?

EDIT:

trying to get Jon O.'s answer working. First I tried

```
(defface my-string-delimiter-face
  '((t (:foreground "red" :weight bold)))
   "My custom face for string delimiters")

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 
          (lambda () 
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\s\"\\|\\s|" 0 solarized-string-delimiter-face t)))))
```

in an attempt to add it to every mode (didn't work)

So then I tried replacing the hook expression with

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp '(("\\s\"\\|\\s|" 0 solarized-string-delimiter-face t)))
```

In an attempt to just get things working, same thing (didn't work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `font-lock-add-keywords` to highlight string delimiters by doing something like the following:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'foo-mode '(("\\s\"\\|\\s|" 0 'my-string-delimiter-face t)))
```

The regexp `"\\s\"\\|\\s|"` matches a single character, which must have syntax class "string quote" (the `\\s\"` part) or "generic string delimiter" (the `\\s|` part). `\s` matches various different character syntax-classes, which you can read about in the Elisp manual under `(elisp)Syntax Tables` and `(elisp)Regexp Backslash`.

It's a little easier to read if you see it without string escaping: `\s"\|\s|`

The `0` means to apply the face to the entire matched string, and the `t` at the end makes this face override any faces that are already present on the string (since many modes will highlight the entire string including the delimiters with `font-lock-string-face` or similar)

`'foo-mode` could be the quoted name of any mode (e.g. `'emacs-lisp-mode`, `'php-mode`), or `nil` to make this change buffer-local in the current buffer only. (In that case you should probably put this in the mode-hooks of the modes you want to apply it to)

`my-string-delimiter-face` could be any existing face, or you could define one by doing something like the following:

```
(defface my-string-delimiter-face
  '((t (:foreground "red" :weight bold)))
   "My custom face for string delimiters")
```

Comment: great answer for a long and rambling question, can't seem to get it working though (explained in an edit to the question since its a bunch of code) thanks for the help!

Comment: @MattBriggs : I think you may need a quote `'` before the face name (`solarized-string-delimiter-face`). I always forget about this because the default font-lock faces work both as variables and quoted symbols. I edited my answer to reflect this -- it seems to work for me now, does it help you?

Comment: @MattBriggs: Also, in your second example above, you would need to write `(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode ...` since `emacs-lisp-mode` is the full name of the major mode.

Comment: the ' was totally it :D Thanks man, learned a lot about emacs figuring this out, and I'm glad my theme looks more like I'm used to!